# How to parse JSON in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I need to parse JSON response from server. JSON is in this format:

See examples lower.

There can be any number of 0,1 tags and any number of elements in the synonyms tag. I need to parse this data into arrays or maybe one array with keys. I do not know how to do it.

```
  Example 1
  words:
     0: 
      synonyms:  
            0: "дисплей"
            1: "процессор"
            2: "монитор"
            3: "интернет"
            4: "смартфон"
            5: "принтер"
            6: "компьютерный"
            7: "ноутбук"
            8: "эвм"
            9: "сервер"


 Example 2
  words:
     0: 
      synonyms:  
            0: "дисплей"
            1: "процессор"
            2: "монитор"
            3: "интернет"
            4: "смартфон"
            5: "принтер"
            6: "компьютерный"
            7: "ноутбук"
            8: "эвм"
            9: "сервер"
     1: 
      synonyms:  
            0: "дисплей"
            1: "процессор"
            2: "монитор"
            3: "интернет"
            4: "смартфон"
            5: "принтер"
            6: "компьютерный"
            7: "ноутбук"
            8: "эвм"
            9: "сервер"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact output you need but the following might help.

Using the below parser

```
const array = [];

Object.keys(words).forEach(wordIndex => {
    const insideObj = words[wordIndex];
    const synObj = insideObj.synonyms;
    const tempArray = [];
    Object.keys(synObj).forEach(objKey => {
        tempArray.push(synObj[objKey]);
    });
    array.push(tempArray);
})
```

For the input:

```
var words = {
    0: {
        synonyms: {
            0: "дисплей",
            1: "процессор",
            2: "монитор",
            3: "интернет",
            4: "смартфон",
            5: "принтер",
            6: "компьютерный",
            7: "ноутбук",
            8: "эвм",
            9: "сервер"
        }      
    },
    1: {
        synonyms: {
            0: "дисплей",
            1: "процессор",
            2: "монитор",
            3: "интернет",
            4: "смартфон",
            5: "принтер",
            6: "компьютерный",
            7: "ноутбук",
            8: "эвм",
            9: "сервер"
        }      
    }
}
```

The Output would be

```
[
  [
    "дисплей",
    "процессор",
    "монитор",
    "интернет",
    "смартфон",
    "принтер",
    "компьютерный",
    "ноутбук",
    "эвм",
    "сервер"
  ],
  [
    "дисплей",
    "процессор",
    "монитор",
    "интернет",
    "смартфон",
    "принтер",
    "компьютерный",
    "ноутбук",
    "эвм",
    "сервер"
  ]
]
```